# want to migrate to python 2.7 from 2.5,but after making changes website doesn't

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, migration

I am trying to migrate from python to 2.7 to 2.5 but after making the required changes to main.py and app.yaml file, my site does not work

please help... what changes should i make to these to get it to work

main.py

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

app.yaml

```
application: cool-gadgets    
version: 1    
runtime: python    
api_version: 1    

handlers:
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico

- url: /gadgets/disney.xml
  static_files: gadgets/disney.xml
  upload: gadgets/disney.xml

- url: /gadgets/wwe.xml
  static_files: gadgets/wwe.xml
  upload: gadgets/wwe.xml

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

**Changes which i made to this to migrate to 2.7**

Main.py

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))


  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: cool-gadgets    
version: 1    
runtime: python27    
api_version: 1    
threadsafe: true    

handlers:
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico

- url: /gadgets/disney.xml
  static_files: gadgets/disney.xml
  upload: gadgets/disney.xml

- url: /gadgets/wwe.xml
  static_files: gadgets/wwe.xml
  upload: gadgets/wwe.xml

- url: .*
  script: main.application
```

Comment: See this doc : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't say "does not work". That provides no useful information. You should say what you see, what error you get, etc.

In your case it seems most likely that you have an indentation error: the `application` at the end of `main.py` needs to be fully to the left, as it is a module-level variable.

Comment: Hi Daniel
After making the above changes I am getting this error(Error 500)
"The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it"